# Get data from database in real time using AJAX

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the data from the database in real time but facing an issue, the java script is not running, i have tried it multiple times and also searched in stackoverflow for answers for my particular type of code but failed.

A simple fetch.php

```
<?php
       include_once('db.php');

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM people";
       $res = mysql_query($sql);
       $result = array();

       while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) )
           array_push($result, array('name' => $row[0],
                                     'age' => $row[1],
                                     'company' => $row[2]));
       echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
?>
```

And the my_script.js

```
$(document).ready( function () {
done();
});

function done() {
      setTimeout( function()  {
      updates(); 
      done();
      }, 200);
}

funtion updates() {
     $.getJSON("fetch.php", function(data) {
        $("ul").empty();

        $.each(data.result, function() {

         $("ul").append("<li>Name: "+this['name']+"</li><li>Age: "+this['age']+"</li><li>Company: "+this['company']+"</li><br />");

         });

     });
     }
```

The data received from the database is not displaying at all, only when it is refreshed and the data from the database is not getting into proper format of table even after using it in the script, and i have established proper database connectivity but i have just not mentioned it here as it is quite simple and since i'm receiving the data but not in the proper format and not in real time.

Thank You.

Comment: any error in your console?

Comment: `function updates() {` missing `c` in `funtion`

Comment: Doing ajax calls every 200ms is not a good idea...

Comment: you should have an error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in your browser console

Comment: also it will be better to do the second call to `done` after the 1st request is finished

Comment: It gives no error, just loads improperly indented data and its not refreshing the page, and the console is not giving any errors. I do not know much about this, can you point the fix by posting it as a code, thanks.

Comment: are you saying there is no typo in your code.. can you post the code as you have in your page..; because the code you have posted here won't work

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right it is give that error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" and im trying to use the code from this page http://technotip.com/2298/fetchextract-data-from-database-without-refreshing-webpage-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use pure ajax. Also please don't use timers, search for an ajax synchronizer. Anyway, if this doesn't work you need to post the database structure.

**fetch.php**

```
<?php
       include_once('db.php');
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM people";
       $res = mysql_query($sql);
       $result = array();
       $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people");
       while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
       $result[] = $obj;
       }
       echo $_GET['callback'] . '{"result":'.json_encode($result).'}';
?>
```

**JS**

```
  $.ajax({
      url: 'fetch.php',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',

   success: function(data) {
      for (var x = 0; x < data.result.length; x++) {
          $("ul").append("<li>Name: "+ data.result.name[x] +"</li><li>Age: "+ data.result.age[x] +"</li><li>Company: "+ data.result.company[x] +"</li><br />");
      }
   },
   error: function () { alert('error'); },
   });
```